# Convert Tweet ID String to a higher base (ie. Base64)

Tags: javascript, json, twitter, utf-8

Tweet IDs are 64 bit decimals stored as strings since JavaScript cannot handle 64 bit integers.  I want to store my Tweets in a Database as JSON using the ID as the key.  To keep the database small, I want to optimize my ID length.  JSON is UTF-8 with a few restricted characters.  So, Base64 is probably best (a-z,A-Z,0-9, $, #).

What's a robust way to do this?  Note, I will need to encode and decode and I am using Node.js so I probably need to leave it as a string when I encode.

Tweet ID Example:  112652479837110273

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213227/fastest-way-to-convert-a-number-to-radix-64-in-javascript

Comment: Why don't you just leave it as it is?

Comment: gr3co, thanks for the link.  As a follow on.  Is there any risk for numbers above 53 bits using this method?

Comment: Musa, I am using CouchDB which tends to take a lot of disk space and the ID in particular has a dramatic impact on disk usage.